# Can pthread_cancel() block?

Tags: c

Can the c function pthread_cancel() block or does it always return immediately? My man page states that:

> The above steps happen asynchronously with respect to the pthread_cancel() call; the return status of pthread_cancel() merely informs the caller whether the cancellation request was successfully queued.

Which certainly suggests not. Are there any situations where the call can block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the call to `pthread_cancel()` does not block. It merely registers a cancel request.

The only situation where it could block is if a thread tried to cancel itself, but that is taken care of in the function implementation: [check this link](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release/pthread_cancel.c)